# How to Populate a listBox depending on the index of another listBox

Tags: c#, dictionary, listbox

Ok. So I have created a dictionary that assigns actors (in a 13,559 line txt file) to their movies (in same txt file). For example, actor 1 is assigned to movies 'a' 'b' and 'c' and actor 2 is assigned to movies 'd' and 'e'. In my dictionary, the keys are string values (actor) and the movies are stored in List and assigned to the keys.

I have attached the GUI that I am using but the jist of it is that I want Actor A's movies to appear in listBox2 when Actor A is selected by the user in listBox1. Of course, if Actor B is selected, I want his movies to be displayed in listBox 2 and Actor A's movies to be removed. In other words, I want listBox2 to constantly update as I scroll through listBox1.

If you have any advice please share it! Thank you!

```
// dictionary already full of actors and movies
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // as index of listBox1 changes, what should I do in this method?
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
using System.Linq

...

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // filter movies according to selected value in first listbox
    var movies = myDic.Where(x => x.Key == listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
    listBox2.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string movie in movies)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(movie);
    }
}
```

Depending on how you're filling `listBox1`, you might need to use `listBox1.SelectedValue` instead of `listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you for the help! But it keeps saying: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source." b/c it doesn't like line1. Any idea? (I tried both of the methods that you told me to try out).

Comment: @theCyclops It's hard to say what is wrong. Check if value of `listBox1.SelectedItem`, is `null` Check if your dictionary is filled with right keys/values etc...

Comment: @theCyclops  You really need to specify how your Dictionary and the ListBox are bound. If you added items to the ListBox using a BindingSource, `listBox1.SelectedItem` will contain the Key, Values pairs all together. Thus, to get the key, you'll have to cast it -> `((KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>)listBox1.SelectedItem).Key)`